# .apk file getting removed from /system/app directory on android 4.1.2

Tags: android, adb

I am trying to install an app on android 4.1.2 using adb shell. This is an app in development which works well on higher android version placed under /system/priv-app/ directory. So this is what I am doing

```
su
mount -o remount,rw /system
cat /sdcard/myapp.apk > /system/app/myapp.apk
chmod 644 /system/app/myapp.apk
reboot
```

Before reboot i verified the file was placed under /system/app with correct permissions. When the phone reboots my app seems to be getting cleared from /system/app directory and i don't see it there anymore. Any clues?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got the problem, this is happening because HTC One Android version is 4.1.2 and the API used in the app are supported on version 4.4.3 or above. So when android is rebooted it is not able to launch the app properly and hence removes it.

Comment: So you app, the physical file, was never removed from /system/app. It is simply getting rejected by PackageManager because of your manifest min sdk?

Answer (score -2):

Are you using real device or emulator? Emulator might be unpacking system image from a file so any change you make to system partition will not persist across boot.

Comment: First of all this is a comment if you are asking a question. To answer it , i am using a real HTC One device

Comment: HTC One has write protection on system partition even if you have root. You will need to do additional work to truely get write access. I have not try to do it myself but there are plenty of guide available.

Answer (score -2):

My suggestion:

1. using `ls -al /system/app/myapp.apk` to see if permission,user/group,size,date all ok.
2. capture logcat to see if anything wrong.(filter using your myapp.apk as key words)

Comment: I have mentioned in my question that file is properly copied to /system/app folder with correct permissions.

Comment: How do i collect logical or logs for my app on real device?

Comment: not only permissions , other info user/group,size,date  also needed.